# How can I install DL_thesis_v2016 package

Tags: packages, installing

I am working on a latex document which does give me the error of DL_thesis_v2016.sty is not found. I am not able how to fix this error and install this package to get things working. I appreciate deeply your help in this matter. Thank you so much.

Comment: it is not a standard package. you should presumably be able to get it from wherever you got the document that uses it

Comment: Google shows a file of that name in [this Git Repo](https://github.com/stephensekula/Dedman-Thesis-Latex-Template/releases/tag/v0.0.1) which forked the Thesis template for Southern Methodist University's Dedman College. (I don't guarantee that this is in fact the file you are looking for.) The `sty` file itself can be downloaded from https://github.com/stephensekula/Dedman-Thesis-Latex-Template/tree/v0.0.1/sty

Comment: If you are using MikTeX, you will need to add the file to the FNDB.  If not, never mind.

Comment: After getting/downloading the file, you may also be interested in: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/277964) or [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/277964).

Comment: Great, thank you so much!